# How create a custom message for method valid () in JOI library?

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

I am validating the property **subscription** like this:

```
Joi.object({
  subscription: Joi.string()
    .valid('starter', 'pro', 'business')
    .required()
    .messages({
      'string.base': `{{#label}} should be a type of string`,
      'string.empty': `{{#label}} must contain value`,
      'any.required': `missing field {{#label}}`,
    }),
})
```

If **subscription** not one of these 'starter', 'pro', 'business', I have a message

**""subscription" must be one of [starter, pro, business]"**

So, how create a custom message for method valid () in JOI library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [any.only](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.7.0#anyonly-1):

> Only some values were allowed, the input didn't match any of them.

Like this:

```
'any.only': `missing field {{#label}}`
```

This will output the following custom error message:

```
Validation Error: missing field "subscription"
```